# How do you set a custom Tooltip location for JTable header?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I set the tooltip location for a JTable header? I have no issue displaying the tooltip, but I would like to place it directly over the column title rather than the default location (under mouse cursor).

I can do this successfully for JTable cells by overriding the `getToolTipLocation` method in the JTable class, but it doesn't seem to work for the table header.

As well, the JTableHeader class doesn't support the `getToolTipLocation` method. I've been toiling with this for a while now and any samples or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong about JTableHeader not supporting getToolTipLocation. It's buried in the JComponent class which JTableHeader is subclassed from. The code example I provided solves my problem. I implemented the code in a class that is subclassed from the JTable class. I'm still getting use to this site and my apologies if the example doesn't seem complete.

```
protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {     
    return new JTableHeader(this.columnModel) {
        Point p = null;
        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
            int colIdx = this.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            Rectangle rect = this.getHeaderRect(colIdx);
            p = rect.getLocation();
            return this.columnModel.getColumn(colIdx).getHeaderValue().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e) {
            return p;
        }
    };
}
```